# Is it possible to update the assigned Azure DSC configuration to a VM via ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, dsc

I need to change the Azure DSC configuration that has been previously assigned to a VM.

I'm trying to do this programatically because it's part of an automation I'm developing and because of this, I'm using ARM Templates.

However, redeploying the same VM DSC extension by ARM Template results in an error stating a VM can't have two of the same extensions, which sounds logical.

What I want to know if it's possible to, by ARM Template, "update" or "modify" the current extension with just one setting changed: The configuration name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - you can update the existing VM extension by providing new configuration in your ARM template. As you have found out, you cannot use a different name for the extension - that would result in two VM extensions of the same type on the VM. Instead, you need to reuse the same name of the existing VM extension when performing the update.